# how is INT returned as INT& in c++?

Tags: c++, reference, return-value

am a c++ beginner and this code really confused me:

```
int global = 100;
int& setGlobal()
{
    return global;    
}
int &a=setGlobal() ;

int main(void){
    a=a+5;
    std::cout<<global<<std::endl;
}
```

The return type of **setGlobal** is **int&** , but **global** is an **int**.

- Please explain to me how does that work?
- Shouldn't it be **return &global** ?

The code that i understand is like this:

```
  int global = 100;
  int& x=global;

  int& setGlobal()
  {
    x+10;
    return x;    
  } 
  int main(void){
    x=x+10;
    std::cout<<global<<std::endl;
    }
```

Maybe my problem is with references.

Comment: In the code you understand, aren't you doing the same thing? You're assigning `int& x` a reference to `int global`

Comment: `int &` as a return type is a reference to an integer. `return &global` would return a pointer to an integer.

Comment: But global is an **int** , the return type should be **int** as well right ?

Comment: The `&` can mean different things in different contexts.  For `int& x = global;` it means `x` is a reference to `global`.  For `return &global;` it means the address of `global` (suitable for use as a pointer, `int*`).

Comment: return is like an assignment to a variable of the returned type. So it is like "int& returnvalue = global", which looks like x in your second code, so hopefully you understand. But be careful: The & has several unrelated usages: After a type it means reference, before a variable it means address of, and before an int value it is the bit-wise-and operator. So return &global won't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A return type of `T&` gets you the reference of the returned object of type `T`.

In your case

```
int& setGlobal()
{
    return global;    
}
```

returns a reference (`int&`) to global. Basically an alias, another way to access the same variable.

This means that

```
int &a=setGlobal() ;
```

Sets `a` as a reference to `global` and any operation on `a` is reflected on `global`.

It should come as no surprise that

```
int main(void){
    a=a+5;
    std::cout<<global<<std::endl;
}
```

prints 105. `a` and `global` are effectively interchangeable in your `main` scope (because one is an alias of the other).

If `setGlobal` returned `&global`, it would be returning the *address* of `global`. The address is the actual location of the variable in memory, it's not an alias. If you wanted to work with pointers, your code would look like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>

int global = 100;
int* setGlobal()
{
    return &global;    
}
int* a=setGlobal() ;

int main(void){
    *a=*a+5;
    std::cout<<global<<std::endl;
}
```

Notice how we can't access the contents of `global` using `a` directly (it's just an address). We must first *dereference* it.

And for good measure, you should also know that, since `setGlobal()` returns a reference to `global` in your example, it can be used directly as an lvalue to access `global` like so:

```
setGlobal() += 5;
```

Putting the above statement just before printing will result in "110" being displayed. Fun stuff! I invite you to read about lvalues and rvalues on your own time as a next step in your C++ journey!